# Typescript error, how to correct this: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ "ada": { "color": string; "backgroundColor": string; }; "ae": { "color": string; "backgroundColor": string; }; "aion": { "color": string; "backgroundColor": string; }; "ant": { "color": string; "backgroundColor": string; }; "ark": { ...; }; ... 81 more ...; "zrx": { ...; }; }' has no index signature.ts(7017)

I have a coinStyles.json file which contains cryptocurrency brand colors for each asset.

The following function plucks out the correct style object based on the asset's id (symbol).

```
import styles from '../../coinStyles.json'
import { ICoinStyle } from '../types'

// Add style to coin square.
export const setStyle = (currency: string): ICoinStyle => styles[currency.toLowerCase()];
```

[image]

I thought I was missing a type for the returned style, so I added `: ICoinStyle` but that didn't help, now it seems that it actually wants me to type the `styles` object which is the JSON. I couldn't find the syntax for that. Or how to do that in this case.

**ICoinStyle**

```
export interface ICoinStyle {
  color: string;
  background: string;
  lightBg?: boolean;
}
```

**coinStyles.json**

```
{
  "ada": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#6297DF"
  },
  "ae": {
    "color": "#F35C8E",
    "backgroundColor": "#000"
  },
  "aion": {
    "color": "#47BEEB",
    "backgroundColor": "#131944"
  },
  "ant": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#26B9DD"
  },
  "ark": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#EF3A40"
  },
  "elf": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#2e60b7"
  },
  "bat": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#FC511F"
  },
  "bch": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#61BE42"
  },
  "bcn": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#EE4486"
  },
  "blt": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#555CEF"
  },
  "bnb": {
    "color": "#F2B940",
    "backgroundColor": "#3E3E3E"
  },
  "bnt": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#3B3B3B"
  },
  "brd": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#FA7B52"
  },
  "btc": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#F5922F"
  },
  "btg": {
    "color": "#FBBE2D",
    "backgroundColor": "#222423"
  },
  "bts": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#3EBBE9"
  },
  "cvc": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#359F74"
  },
  "dai": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#f7B04A"
  },
  "dash": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#1175B4"
  },
  "dcr": {
    "color": "#3AD6A3",
    "backgroundColor": "#2F76FB"
  },
  "dgb": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#022552"
  },
  "dgd": {
    "color": "#F0C838",
    "backgroundColor": "#212429"
  },
  "doge": {
    "color": "#333333",
    "backgroundColor": "#B99E3D"
  },
  "dnt": {
    "color": "#71F7F9",
    "backgroundColor": "#273284"
  },
  "gbyte": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#2D3E4F"
  },
  "eos": {
    "color": "#F0F5F8",
    "backgroundColor": "#443F53"
  },
  "enj": {
    "color": "#26D1CC",
    "backgroundColor": "#36245E"
  },
  "etc": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#678F74"
  },
  "eth": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#5C607F"
  },
  "fct": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#578299"
  },
  "fuel": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#093156"
  },
  "fun": {
    "color": "#9E235C",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
  },
  "gas": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#719361"
  },
  "gno": {
    "color": "#009CBC",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
  },
  "gnt": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#083F6C"
  },
  "lend": {
    "color": "#0DA2C2",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
  },
  "icn": {
    "color": "#4D6F8B",
    "backgroundColor": "#829AAE"
  },
  "icx": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#3CA8B9"
  },
  "iot": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#333"
  },
  "lsk": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#0D468F"
  },
  "ltc": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#CDCDCD"
  },
  "lun": {
    "color": "#F04725",
    "backgroundColor": "#191B22"
  },
  "kmd": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#3C6363"
  },
  "maid": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#5C91C9"
  },
  "mana": {
    "color": "#F57028",
    "backgroundColor": "#D1C7BE"
  },
  "mco": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#111A32"
  },
  "mkr": {
    "color": "#F0F2F3",
    "backgroundColor": "#2ABB9C"
  },
  "mona": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#B6A170"
  },
  "nano": {
    "color": "#4E92DF",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF",
    "lightBg": true
  },
  "nem": {
    "color": "#212033",
    "backgroundColor": "#2DB5AB"
  },
  "neo": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#4EB704"
  },
  "nmr": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#000"
  },
  "omg": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#2159EC"
  },
  "ont": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#39A4BC"
  },
  "pay": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#353437"
  },
  "pivx": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#7C68A4"
  },
  "poe": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#292929"
  },
  "poly": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#4C5995"
  },
  "powr": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#1FBBA9"
  },
  "qash": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#1F4BB4"
  },
  "qtum": {
    "color": "#359bce",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF",
    "lightBg": true
  },
  "rep": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#412766"
  },
  "salt": {
    "color": "#22272f",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF",
    "lightBg": true
  },
  "sia": {
    "color": "#34EC86",
    "backgroundColor": "#7F8C8D"
  },
  "spank": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#FF6195"
  },
  "snm": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#131822"
  },
  "snt": {
    "color": "#0BD09F",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF"
  },
  "steem": {
    "color": "#0BD09F",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFF",
    "lightBg": true
  },
  "strat": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#1f88c7"
  },
  "storj": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#2E86FB"
  },
  "theta": {
    "color": "#20D7C2",
    "backgroundColor": "#1A1D25"
  },
  "trx": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#222423"
  },
  "tusd": {
    "color": "#62C6FF",
    "backgroundColor": "#1D294F"
  },
  "usdt": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#2EA07C"
  },
  "usd": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#CACCB7"
  },
  "usdc": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#2775C9"
  },
  "waves": {
    "color": "#000",
    "backgroundColor": "#105CFB"
  },
  "wtc": {
    "color": "#8125FB",
    "backgroundColor": "#59EFDC"
  },
  "vet": {
    "color": "#AA77CE",
    "backgroundColor": "#B4E8FF",
    "lightBg": true
  },
  "xmr": {
    "color": "#4C4C4C",
    "backgroundColor": "#FC6621"
  },
  "xlm": {
    "color": "#07A2CC",
    "backgroundColor": "#CEEBF6",
    "lightBg": true
  },
  "xrp": {
    "color": "#23292F",
    "backgroundColor": "#1B84E6"
  },
  "xvg": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#3BA3CA"
  },
  "zec": {
    "color": "#000",
    "backgroundColor": "#EBB451"
  },
  "zen": {
    "color": "#5EFFB5",
    "backgroundColor": "#1C3871"
  },
  "zil": {
    "color": "#50C0BE",
    "backgroundColor": "#46494B"
  },
  "zrx": {
    "color": "#FFF",
    "backgroundColor": "#383838"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler has no idea that `currency.toLowerCase()` will be a valid index into the `styles` object.  So you have to assure it of that fact.  The easiest way is just to be very strict about what `setStyle()` will accept:

```
export const setStyle = (currency: keyof typeof styles): ICoinStyle => styles[currency]; // okay
```

The above will *only* accept `currency` values that are the keys of `styles` and are already the right case (so no `.toLowerCase()`).

---

If you'd like to be able to accept *any string* as `currency` and throw a purely runtime error if it isn't one of the valid values, you could use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to help you:

```
// check if k is a key of obj
function isKeyof<T>(k: keyof any, obj: T): k is keyof T {
  return k in obj;
}

export const setStyle = (currency: string): ICoinStyle => {
  const currencyLowerCase = currency.toLowerCase();
  if (isKeyof(currencyLowerCase, styles)) {
    return styles[currencyLowerCase]; // okay
  } else {
    throw new Error("YOU LIED TO ME ABOUT " + currency);
  }
}
```

Here you explicitly check that taking `currency.toLowerCase()` is a valid key of `styles` and throw an error if not.  The only other reasonable option is to return `ICoinStyle | undefined` like this:

```
export const setStyle = (currency: string): ICoinStyle | undefined => {
  const currencyLowerCase = currency.toLocaleLowerCase();
  if (isKeyof(currencyLowerCase, styles)) {
    return styles[currencyLowerCase];
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

Hope one of those helps you.  Good luck!